# Handle snmp traps and informs on localhost using node js

Tags: node.js, snmp, snmp-trap

I am trying to listen for snmp traps on the standard UDP 162 port and then parse and output them.

I have looked at snmpjs and snmp-native plugins for node and they both seem to major on the generation of agents. What I would like to do is listen and decode traps and informs that are forwarded to my localhost (maybe even acknowledge informs). I know I could spend quite some time with dgram and ASN.1BER but would prefer to use already written snmp code.

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
//var snmp = require('snmpjs');
var snmp = require('snmp-native');

var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

server.on("listening", function() {
    var addr = server.address();
    console.log("Server listening "+ addr.address + ":" + addr.port);
});

server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
    console.log("From " + rinfo.address + ":" + rinfo.port);
    console.log("server got: " + msg);
    //console.log("Parse: " + snmp.parseMessage({raw:msg}));
    console.log("Parse: " + snmp.parse(msg));
});

server.bind(162);
```

Both snmp parse functions cause errors, the first is parseMessage not defined, and it's not clear in the snmpjs documents how to create the correct object http://wesolows.github.com/node-snmpjs/protocol.html#parseMessage(arg). And I can't use the snmpjs agent as there is no on message event.

The second parse from snmp-native, I get an error that the buffer is not an int....

```
Error: Buffer 06082b06010603010105 does not appear to be an Integer
at Object.parseInteger (/usr/share/node/node_modules/snmp-native/lib/asn1ber.js:318:15)
```

Any pointers would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node-snmpjs 0.0.4 now contains a simple trap listener that emits events on traps.  An Express-style interface could be added very easily to match what the Agent does.  See the [GitHub commit](https://github.com/wesolows/node-snmpjs/commit/7fbc2f876ba29c58e42e52fd8d765f2997cfdd08) adding this functionality for an example consumer.  More work will be needed to make this suitable for production use.